# Why do I get wrong number of keys in loglikelihood dictionary. Expected: 9165. Got: 9161

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, artificial-intelligence, nlp-question-answering

```
# Build the freqs dictionary for later uses
freqs = count_tweets({}, train_x, train_y)

# UNQ_C2 GRADED FUNCTION: train_naive_bayes

def train_naive_bayes(freqs, train_x, train_y):
    '''
    Input:
        freqs: dictionary from (word, label) to how often the word appears
        train_x: a list of tweets
        train_y: a list of labels correponding to the tweets (0,1)
    Output:
        logprior: the log prior. (equation 3 above)
        loglikelihood: the log likelihood of you Naive bayes equation. (equation 6 above)
    '''
    loglikelihood = {}
    logprior = 0

    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # calculate V, the number of unique words in the vocabulary
    vocab = set([pair[0] for pair in freqs.keys()])
    V = len(vocab)  

    # calculate N_pos, N_neg, V_pos, V_neg
    N_pos = N_neg =  0
    for pair in freqs.keys():
        # if the label is positive (greater than zero)
        if pair[1] > 0:

            # Increment the number of positive words by the count for this (word, label) pair
            N_pos += freqs[pair]

        # else, the label is negative
        else:

            # increment the number of negative words by the count for this (word,label) pair
            N_neg += freqs[pair]

    # Calculate D, the number of documents
    D = len(train_y)

    # Calculate D_pos, the number of positive documents
    D_pos = sum(train_y)

    # Calculate D_neg, the number of negative documents
    D_neg = D - D_pos

    # Calculate logprior
    logprior = np.log(D_pos) - np.log(D_neg)
    
    # For each word in the vocabulary...
    for word in vocab:
        # get the positive and negative frequency of the word
        freq_pos = lookup(freqs,word,1)
        freq_neg = lookup(freqs,word,0)

        # calculate the probability that each word is positive, and negative
        p_w_pos = (freq_pos + 1) / (N_pos + V)
        p_w_neg = (freq_neg + 1) / (N_neg + V)

        # calculate the log likelihood of the word
        loglikelihood[word] = np.log(p_w_pos / p_w_neg)

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return logprior, loglikelihood


# UNQ_C3 (UNIQUE CELL IDENTIFIER, DO NOT EDIT)
logprior, loglikelihood = train_naive_bayes(freqs, train_x, train_y)
print(logprior)
print(len(loglikelihood))
```

> 

```
0.0
9161
Wrong number of keys in loglikelihood dictionary. 
    Expected: 9165.
    Got: 9161.
```

I've checked and tried over and over again but still got the wrong result, the methond is like below:

Instructions

Given a freqs dictionary, train_x (a list of tweets) and a train_y (a list of labels for each tweet), implement a naive bayes classifier.

Calculate  
You can then compute the number of unique words that appear in the freqs dictionary to get your    (you can use the set function).

Calculate    and  
Using your freqs dictionary, you can compute the positive and negative frequency of each word    and   .

Calculate   , and  
Using freqs dictionary, you can also compute the total number of positive words and total number of negative words    and   .

Calculate   ,   ,  
Using the train_y input list of labels, calculate the number of documents (tweets)   , as well as the number of positive documents (tweets)    and number of negative documents (tweets)   .

Calculate the probability that a document (tweet) is positive  () , and the probability that a document (tweet) is negative  ()

Calculate the logprior
the logprior is  ()−()

Calculate log likelihood
Finally, you can iterate over each word in the vocabulary, use your lookup function to get the positive frequencies,   , and the negative frequencies,   , for that specific word.

Compute the positive probability of each word  () , negative probability of each word  ()  using equations 4 & 5.
()=+1+(4)
()=+1+(5)

Note: We'll use a dictionary to store the log likelihoods for each word. The key is the word, the value is the log likelihood of that word).

You can then compute the loglikelihood:  (()()) .

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue when running on my own server.
However, when running from the Coursera server, I get the correct
number. My assumption is that the dataset has changed since Coursera
loaded it in the material.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34584913)